# Override ChoiceField choice attribute with for loop in Django views

Tags: python, django

I m trying to override ChoiceField in forms in which i can loop through specific object in my views,
But i Failed cause i only get in the template form only the last item in the list.. 
need some help to get all the choices i need from this object.

models.py

```
 class TourPackageBuyer(models.Model):
    tour = models.ForeignKey(TourPackage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null =True) production

    number_choice = [(i,i) for i in range(6)]
    number_choice_2 = [(i,i) for i in range(18)]
    number_choice_3 = [(i,i) for i in range(60)]

    user = models.CharField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, max_length=200) 
    num_of_adults = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, choices= number_choice_2, null=True)
    num_of_children = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, choices= number_choice_3, null=True)

    hotel = models.ManyToManyField(PackageHotel, blank=True)### thats the field
```

forms.py

```
class TourPackageBuyerForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TourPackageBuyer
        date = datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y')
        intDate = int(date)
        limitDate = intDate + 1
        YEARS= [x for x in range(intDate,limitDate)]
        # YEARS=  [2020,2021]
        Months = '1',
        # fields = '__all__'      
        exclude = ('user','tour','invoice','fees', 'paid_case')
        widgets = {
            'pickup_date': SelectDateWidget(empty_label=("Choose Year", "Choose Month", "Choose Day")),
            'hotel': Select(),

            # 'pickup_date': forms.DateField.now(),

        }
    hotel = forms.ChoiceField(choices=[]) ### Thats the field i m trying to override
```

views.py

```
def TourPackageBuyerView(request, tour_id):
    user = request.user
    tour = TourPackage.objects.get(id=tour_id)
    tour_title = tour.tour_title
    hotels = tour.hotel.all()

    form = TourPackageBuyerForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    ### im looping through specific items in the model in many to many field
    for h in hotels:
        form.fields['hotel'].choices = (h.hotel, h.hotel), ### when this loop it just give the last item in the form in my template!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning the value of `choices` every time through the loop, so you'll only get the last value you assign once the loop is finished.

You can fix this by replacing this:

```
for h in hotels:
    form.fields['hotel'].choices = (h.hotel, h.hotel),
```

With this list comprehension:

```
form.fields['hotel'].choices = [(h.hotel, h.hotel) for h in hotels]
```

or if you want a tuple as output you can do:

```
form.fields['hotel'].choices = tuple((h.hotel, h.hotel) for h in hotels)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i used the list comprehension and it worked with me ..